# Django/Wagtail : django-debug-toolbar gives 404 error when cicking on panel

Tags: python, django, wagtail

the toolbar shows nice and clean, but when i click on a panel to see if it really works, it gives me a 404: Not Found error.
I have checked lots of answers and etc but they were from really old versions and i'm afraid i missed some important changelog.

my urls.py

```
import debug_toolbar
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls
from search import views as search_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    path('search/', search_views.search, name='search'),

]

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + [
    path("", include(wagtail_urls)),
    path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and my dev.py

```
from .base import *

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'hidden'

# SECURITY WARNING: define the correct hosts in production!
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] 

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + [
    'debug_toolbar'
]

MIDDLEWARE = MIDDLEWARE + [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

INTERNAL_IPS = ("127.0.0.1")

try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

i'm following this video tutorial for it https://youtu.be/jxUeJsR_XSs?list=PLMQHMcNi6ocsS8Bfnuy_IDgJ4bHRRrvub

EDIT: i fixed it by putting

```
path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
```

in my urlpatterns function at urls.py

Comment: The documentation states that the middleware should be included as early as possible, you are currently appending it to the end. Could be an issue? https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#enabling-middleware

Comment: @Iain thx for the answer, about that, after reading the docs again it makes sense to be it. In order to fix that, i have to Redo everything i've wrote on these files again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: i fixed it by putting

```
path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
```

in my urlpatterns function at urls.py